# Getting Error while using SendKeys with PhantomJs C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am trying to use phantomjs for one of our application to perform headless browser testing. I am stuck with below error, when trying to enter a value into the field:

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Unexpected error. TypeError -
>   undefined is not a constructor (evaluating
>   '_getTagName(currWindow).toLowerCase()')

It works perfectly with Chrome, FF, IE and also with headless Chrome. I did some research, but not able to resolve the issue.

Understand that PhantomJs is faster than any other browser so added explicit wait and tried with `Thread.Sleep`, but still the same issue. However, click on button on the same page works properly, finding issue with SendKeys.
Below is the code ( phantomjs 2.2.1 ):

```
        var driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://portal-sandbox.afterpay.com");
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();

        var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.ClassName("button")));
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        //taking screenshot to debug
        sc = driver.GetScreenshot();
        sc.SaveAsFile("f://atest1.jpg");

        var email = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[name=\"email\"]"));
        email.SendKeys("abc@xyz.com"); //getting error on this line
        driver.FindElementByClassName("button").Click();
        sc = driver.GetScreenshot();
        sc.SaveAsFile("f://atest2.jpg");
```

Tried following different solutions 
1) google.com with entering values it works fine (just to check if sendKeys works)
2) updated PhantomJs.exe 1.9.8, but the same result. 
3) Javascript executor to enter the value - no luck
4) Used Actions to build and perform - same result

So, not sure, if this issue is with phantomJs or with application not supporting entering values with phantomJs.

Any Help really appreciated.